# How do I safely export my database and import it on a new server?

Tags: database, trigger

I will move a CiviCRM installation to another server and realized some strange database issues: it was not possible to save contacts with phone number anymore. The problem are the triggers in the database: both `civicrm_phone_before_update` and `civicrm_phone_before_insert` call a function `civicrm_strip_non_numeric()`. On export of the whole database these triggers and functions are exported with "definers" - database users which do not exist anymore in the new database.

So it seems that you cannot easily dump your CiviCRM database and import your dump to a fresh database. How should I process that?

And why are there these triggers in the database? Why is this not handled on the level of the app?

Comment: I am not sure... does --skip-triggers also skip functions? The main problem for me is the civicrm_strip_non_numeric() which definer is not the current database user. The triggers are working but when the method is called I get the error about the invalid definer

Comment: You should be able to run the perl referenced in the above to remove all of this: perl -pi -e 's#\/\*\!5001[7|3].*?`[^\*]*\*\/##g' /path/to/mysqldump.sql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can export the civicrm database without triggers and functions and After importing and making sure you have CiviCRM working, recreate the triggers by running 'civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1' in browser

Comment: To make a dump without triggers and function: `mysqldump --skip-triggers --skip-routines`